# Simulate a time series

Tags: r, time-series

In a recent online course on macroeconomic forecasting, there was an excercise to model

```
y(t) = 3.0 + 0.55 y(t-1) + e(t)
```

where `e(t)` is defined as

```
et <- c(-1.2138662, -0.2854597, 0.5902700, 0.8285463, -0.9954260, -0.3716332)
```

Now I tried to do this in R (the course used EViews), however I do not come to the solution given there: 5.648 for the 5th element.
I tried (similar to this [blogpost](http://ellisp.github.io/blog/2015/11/21/arima-sims)):

```
y <- rep(NA,6)
y[1] <- 0
y[2] <- 3 + 0.55*y[1]+et[1]
y[3] <- 3 + 0.55*y[2]+et[2]
y[4] <- 3 + 0.55*y[3]+et[3]
y[5] <- 3 + 0.55*y[4]+et[4]
y[6] <- 3 + 0.55*y[5]+et[5]
```

and then

```
y <- rep(NA,6)
y[1] <- et[1]
y[2] <- 3 + 0.55*y[1]+et[2]
y[3] <- 3 + 0.55*y[2]+et[3]
y[4] <- 3 + 0.55*y[3]+et[4]
y[5] <- 3 + 0.55*y[4]+et[5]
y[6] <- 3 + 0.55*y[5]+et[6]
```

and then

```
arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=0.55), n=6, innov=head(et,6)+3)
```

However all three methods give different results. I wonder why this is, I am afraid I did not understand something basic.

Comment: Yes I agree the first two methods must lead to different results. However, none of all three methods gives y[5]==5.648, the solution given in the exercise.

Comment: @Khashaa: it is (the solution was rounded to three numbers)? How did you get this?

Comment: Your first approach has typo. Check `et[i]`terms

Comment: `Reduce(function(x, e){3+0.55*x+e}, et[2:6], init=0, accumulate=TRUE)` in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arima.sim` has a "burn-in" period in order to reach stationarity. Argument `n.start` sets the length of this period, and it must has length `ar` + `ma`. For an `AR(1)` process, `n.start` must be at least 1. Note, if you don't specify `n.start`, `arima.sim` will automatically compute a reasonable one for you.

Given `n.start` (either a specified one or auto-computed one), `arima.sim` then randomly sample `n.start` innovations for "burn-in". It is right because of this random procedure, you will get different result from one run to another:

```
## innovations of length 6
et <- c(-1.2138662, -0.2854597, 0.5902700, 0.8285463, -0.9954260, -0.3716332)

set.seed(0)
arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.55), n = 6, innov = et, n.start = 1)
#[1] -0.5192413 -0.5710424  0.2761967  0.9804545 -0.4561760 -0.6225300

set.seed(1)
arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.55), n = 6, innov = et, n.start = 1)
# [1] -1.55841580 -1.14258839 -0.03815361  0.80756181 -0.55126700 -0.67483005
```

We can eliminate such randomness, by providing a set of starting innovations using `start.innov` argument. Note, this vector must has length `n.start`:

```
## fixing starting innovation at 0; i.e., `y[0] = 0`, so `y[1] = et[1]`.
arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.55), n = 6, innov = et, n.start = 1,
          start.innov = 0)
# [1] -1.21386620 -0.95308611  0.06607264  0.86488625 -0.51973856 -0.65748941
```

Now, compare this last `arima.sim` with the following:

```
y <- rep(NA, 6)
y[1] <- et[1]
y[2] <- 0.55 * y[1] + et[2]
y[3] <- 0.55 * y[2] + et[3]
y[4] <- 0.55 * y[3] + et[4]
y[5] <- 0.55 * y[4] + et[5]
y[6] <- 0.55 * y[5] + et[6]

# [1] -1.21386620 -0.95308611  0.06607264  0.86488625 -0.51973856 -0.65748941
```

We have everything completely reproducible.

The above generates zero-mean time series; if you want mean at 3, shift the result by `+3` yourself:

```
y <- y + 3
```

Comment: This is really helpful. It does not come to the result I was looking for (5.648), but now I understand why: the first element is set to et[1], which makes perfect sense to me, but is not what the instructors did.

Comment: @KarstenW. `e <- c(0, et[-1]+3); arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.55), n = 6, innov = e, n.start = 1,
          start.innov = 0)` and you should accept Zheyuan Li's answer.